# How to use spatialite and the tz database to tag many points with time zones

Tags: spatialite, time, gpx

I have a spatialite database containing every journey I have made every day since April 2003. I use this importer I co-wrote to populate a 'tracklines' table and a 'trackpoints' table from gpx files: [ptrv/gpx2spatialite](https://github.com/ptrv/gpx2spatialite).

For another application (the geolocating of all my sms text messages!), I want to tag the points (probably in a separate table) with a time zone from the [tz database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), giving me a way of deriving the local time for these points as a starting point to matching up with text messages I have sent.

I have tried with python and the timezonefinder module but it is super slow, hence turning to spatialite since the points are in a spatialite database already. I then tried to follow some of Alessandro Furieri's excellent spatialite cookbook recipes but I can't find something that hits the spot.

I know I need to make a spatial index but I'm confused about whether the points or the time zones need one (or both?) and then what a moderately efficient query would be to associate millions of points with timezones. I say moderately because I would only have to run this once and store the results in a table (unless someone knows a better way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to download the shapefile of timezones from [here](http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/). Import the whole polygon shapefile into your spatialite database, then contruct an update query using `ST_Contains()` on the points table to find which tz it's in.

You will definitely want to setup an index on the timezones table, and use it in your query.

(edit...)
Referring to the comment below:
I think you have the spatial index backwards. You created an index on the timezones table (correctly) but you refer to a index on the trackpoints table (incorrect).
It should be:

`... AND z.ROWID in (SELECT ROWID from SpatialIndex WHERE f_table_name='tz_world_mp' AND search_frame = t.geom)`

Comment: I imported the timezones shapefile and made a spatial index on it and tried the following sql: `select trkpt_uid, utctimestamp, x(t.geom) as long, y(t.geom) as lat, tzid
from trackpoints as t, tz_world_mp as z
where user_uid = 1 and
strftime('%Y-%m-%d', utctimestamp) = '2015-01-01' and
ST_Contains(z.Geometry, t.geom)
order by utctimestamp` I only performed the test on tracks from one day (1129 trackpoints) which took 2m35s. I tried adding `and t.ROWID in (SELECT ROWID from SpatialIndex WHERE f_table_name='trackpoints' AND search_frame = c.geom)` after 35 minutes I gave up.

Comment: Last week I edited my answer, responding to your comment. Did that help?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! I'd completely misunderstood what table I should be running the spatial index query and what the 'search_frame' should be. My query for those 1129 trackpoints is now down to a couple of seconds!